# Reusing scopes as filters on `includes` eager-loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Breaking it down to a minimal example:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :profiles
  has_many :addresses, through: :profiles
end

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :addresses
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :profile

  def self.active_by_date
    where(is_active: true).order('updated_at DESC')
  end
end

class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.includes(profiles: :addresses)
  end
end
```

Suppose that in the above controller action, I want to eager-load the active addresses, sorted by date, for each user's profiles. I could do this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :profiles
  has_many :addresses, through: :profiles
  has_many :active_addresses_by_date, through: :profiles,
    source: :addresses, class_name: Address,
    conditions: ['address.is_active = ?', true],
    order: 'address.updated_at DESC'
end

class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.includes(profiles: :active_addresses_by_date)
  end
end
```

But since I can't reuse the `active_by_date` scope on `Address`, the condition and order now exist in two places. I'd like to DRY this up so that, as in the first version, the concept of "active addresses by date" exists only in the `Address` model. Ideally, in the view I would be able to call `@users.each { |user| user.addresses.active_by_date }` without firing any queries. Is this possible under ActiveRecord, and if so, how would I go about it?

Comment: I stumbled into this issue a couple of days ago. I ended up overriding the accessor for the association, but would love to see what other solutions there are.

Comment: I didn't know it was even possible to override the association method and still have the `includes` work, but I just tested it and apparently it is. That's an improvement in my book, though it also increases the amount of eager-loading-specific "stuff" in the `User` model. Like you, I'm hoping there's a better solution. =)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't understand something, but that would happen if you change `active_by_date` to

```
  def self.active_by_date
    where("addresses.is_active = ?", true).order('addresses.updated_at DESC')
  end
```

wouldn't it be possible to then call `User.includes(profiles: :addresses).active_by_date` ?

Comment: `active_by_date` would then need to be defined on `User` as well as `Address`, reintroducing the problem of condition/order duplication.

Comment: You may solve it witn module incusion, concerns. Just take the common code out to a separate module!

Comment: That seems impractical if wanting to reuse scopes is common -- you'd have a multitude of tiny concerns that are all only relevant to one model. At any rate, I realized this approach doesn't work for another reason: It only returns users who have active addresses. I want to return _all_ users, and eager-load their active addresses if they have any.